# typescript: second type depends on first type selection

Tags: typescript, conditional-statements

I need your help so much.

I'm strugglin to find the best approach to conditionally add `CardFullProps[]` and `CardHalfProps[]` to `CarouselProps[slides]` property.

Something like, if the received data has `type : CardType.full` the `CarouselProps[slides]` type is `CardFullProps[]`, else `CardHalfProps[]`.

```js
export enum CardType {
    full,
    half
}

type Slides = CardFullProps & CardHalfProps;

export type CarouselProps = {
    type: CardType;
    slides: Slides[];
    slidesPerView?: number;
};
```

Help me Obi-Type-Kenoby, you are my only help.

Just another padawan

Answer (score 0):

If a type can be altered by some sort of input, then it needs to be a [generic type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).

You would then use that generic type in [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html):

```
export type CarouselProps<T extends CardType> = {
    type: T;
    slides: (T extends CardType.full ? CardFullProps : CardHalfProps)[];
    slidesPerView?: number;
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgJwCYDECuAbDAFBB7MAZygF4oBvAWACgoo4AuKAOzQFsAjCBGujp1p268oAYwHsuPagF8aNUJFiIkACTgYAZrgLEyVWvQlDpc6jQgAPMHgTAoEQcuQAVcNAN06mzBgA0InQAFhqaNGYW1rb2itDw+GiEEDj4RAA8Lg6WwI5IxPFIbpAAfKQUgVCxTC4A3BWEGACWSBCETAAUmVY5zHnOhe4AdD5YUAD8-ehYOkRQTAXqWjOEAJQA2gC6dYZ0Dc2t2NwAao0QAO5jxlLbMts0onjMhPYjKbrziHiJyctpBUUQYa+Ur6ERVfoAoFYAKGPYtNpQNbkRgARj8UH4ACZ0eIAMwyDbheTUB5PF6+ZYAUQQ+AQHwSSTe6X+Q1eIPKhnBLMgUP8IjhrSYSNRBKgAHoxZV3A4abYieYSY9nlAQktUgj4l9Gb9uYDVZp2Z4pZB6QMefqYbsmvChciGCiCfL7kr7PqqbK6c4tT91X8VJD9Yawe5TQHQpaoAKEcL7eisTiGPiNuLJbEZbTwkA)

---

Alternatively, you could create a lookup type that ties together the card types and the types of the props:

```
type CardPropsMapping = {
  [CardType.full]: CardFullProps,
  [CardType.half]: CardHalfProps,
}

export type CarouselProps<T extends CardType> = {
    type: T;
    slides: CardPropsMapping[T][];
    slidesPerView?: number;
};
```

This would likely scale better if that enum grows in the future.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=25&ssc=3&pln=16&pc=1#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)

---

You can use all this with a generic function so you don't have to write the card type twice:

```
function makeSlides<T extends CardType>(props: CarouselProps<T>) {
  //...
}

makeSlides({
  type: CardType.half,
  slides: [{a:1}]
})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=47&ssc=1&pln=52&pc=3#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)

Comment: There's an even easier way and that's to use a [discriminate union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions): `type CarouselProps = { type: CardType.full, slides: CardFullProps[] } | { type: CardType.half, slides: CardHalfProps[] }`

Comment: Sure that would work, too :)